# Why using Integer reference as case constant in switch giving error?

Tags: java, switch-statement, compile-time-constant

```
public class Switch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


      final  Integer i=new Integer(2);

        switch(i)
        {
        case i:System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }

}
```

When I am compiling it then it is giving error saying that case must be a consatnt but if I write below code then no error.Why so?

```
public class Switch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


      final  int i=2;

        switch(i)
        {
        case i:System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `2` is a compile-time constant. `new Integer(2)` is not compile-time constant.

Comment: Have you tried using `i.intValue()` ?

Comment: @luizfzs Have you tried that? That would not work as a case label, as I am certain you discovered when you tried it.

Comment: Lew Bloch, My suggestion was to use it as the switch statemente, not as a case label. My comment did not clear that, though.